# python signal before operating system sleeps

Tags: python, signals

I have a process which i would like to close before the OS it is running on gets put to sleep. I have been looking into the `signal` library which is part of the standard python library but I cannot capture the OS sleep.

Is there a way across Linux, OSX and windows to capture the OS sleep event signal?

Comment: I am not sure but I think that when the OS will go to sleep it will send a `SIGSTOP` or `SIGTSTP ` signal to all the processes. Because then when the OS comes back from the sleep it can continue the processes by sending `SIGCONT ` signal. The OS will send a `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL` when it does not wish to continue the process later, they will terminate the process completely. I just read the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals Maybe I have understood it wrong.